# C# 7 Compiler Error - Pattern Matching

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

For some reason, `M1()` causes a compiler error, while `M2()`, which does the same thing, causes no error. Any idea why?

Using `false ==` should be the same as using the not operator, `!`.

> Use of unassigned local variable 'i'

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int x = 8;

        M1(x);
        M2(x);
    }  // Main()

    public static void M1(Object obj) {
        if (false == (obj is int i))  // Causes ERROR on WriteLine
            return;

        System.Console.WriteLine(i); // Use of unassigned local variable 'i'
    }

    public static void M2(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj is int i))  // OKAY
            return;

        System.Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
} // class Program
```

Comment: seems that i is out of scope for M1 - edge case find?

Comment: @Aominè I can see it in VS 15.2 (VS->help->about)... What do you use?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Clearly not. If `i` were out of scope, the error wouldn't say "unassigned local variable". You can only get that error for variables that are in scope.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I use Rider but I didn't get the error until I ran the program. I thought I was using my VS 2017 then until you asked the question.

Comment: @Aominè I see. No idea about Rider. I suspect one need to carefully read through actual specification to get correct answer... Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) recommend `if (a is Foo b)` to check "expression definitely assigns the match variable" - there is a good chance specification implicitly disallows all other comparisons with true/false.

Comment: @hvd Agreed. It does not make a diff if you do `if (false == (obj is int i))` or `if ((obj is int i) == false)` - maybe optimizing the assignment away bc the if-condition  is false anyway? Where could one look up how this pattern matching is done interally? (using vs2017 community with 4.6.1 console app)

Comment: also `if((obj is int i) == true) Write(i)` doesn't work, `false` is not causing problem, there is something wrong about `==` operator and pattern matching.

Comment: by the way, its time to go donwvote posts that claimed `== false` is same as `!` ^_^

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, claiming `== false` is same as `!` was already wrong prior to C# 7 as nullable bools behave differently. For `bool? b = null;`, `if (b == false)` compiles just fine, but `if(!b)` complains about not being able to cast from `bool?` to `bool`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The issue here is with the way the compiler handles "definitely assigned when true". `!` inverts that; `== false` doesn't. So for the code:

```
if (!(obj is int i))
        return;

System.Console.WriteLine(i);
```

The compiler can infer that if `obj is int i` is false, the `!` inverts that, thus `return` will occur if it's not an `int`. Therefore `i` can be allowed to "leak" into subsequent code safely.

However, the same rules do not apply to `== false`. Whilst semantically identical to a human reader of the code, the compiler treats `!` and `== false` as very different things. So for:

```
if (false == (obj is int i))
```

the compiler baulks and takes the view it cannot know the assignment state of `i`, thus the error.

For a discussion on this, please see [Incorrect "Use of unassigned local variable" for `(x is T y) == false`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/20969).

The moral of the story: avoid comparing to `false` and use `!` when using C# patterns.

**EDIT**

It should be noted that `== false` is not a special case here. Any use of `==` removes the ability of the compiler to determine "definitely assigned when true". For example, the following code compiles:

```
object x = 1;
if (!(x is bool y))
    return 0;

var z = y;
```

But add a `== true` and it no longer does:

```
object x = 1;
if (!(x is bool y == true))
    return 0;

var z = y; // error: use of an unassigned variable
```

**EDIT2**

Incidently, for anyone who uses `if (expression == false)` because they find `if (!expression)` difficult to read, you may be interested to know that [the syntax, `if !(expression)` is being considered for C# 8](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/882).

Comment: `!` is still an operator anyway, it has implementation like `==` has. why cant compiler optimize `== false` away? note that `== false` part is constant. it can be optimized, but unfortunately compiler emits error before doing that.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, it's quite possibly it could be improved that way. If you feel passonate about it, then please [raise an issue on the C# language repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues) to request it.

Comment: @DavidArno there is already issue for that there: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/801

Comment: @Evk, hmm, I see I commented on that issue! I'd completely forgotten about it <blush/>

Comment: thanks for the link, I'm supporting that issue not because I'm fan of `== false` but because that syntax is not terribly wrong. imho it should work in either case.

Comment: Given that problem is not in pattern matching, you can provide a case where pattern matching is not used, but C# compiler return same error. For example: `int x; bool t = true; if((t && int.TryParse("1", out x)) == true) { Console.WriteLine(x); }`

Comment: @PetSerAl so you mean this code works if you remove == true?

Comment: @Evk Yes. With `== true` removed, this piece of code compiles without error.

Answer (score 0):

good find, here is what I think. note that this is definitely something that could be fixed, but I'm trying to find a reasoning for it. note that this is not accurate answer. just saying!

its not just `false ==` that causes this problem, but also `== true` causes `i` to become unusable in either branch, so I went ahead and wrote this.

```
var x = obj is int i;
if(x) Console.WriteLine(i);
```

you get the same error. as you can see if `x` is true then `i` should be initialized, right? unless you start to muck with `x` value! here `x` is not constant therefor we can not guarantee that `x` always remains true before executing if statement.

how ever compiler can compute constant values and expressions at compile time. I'm not sure what is happening here but what I think is

`if((obj is int i) == false)`

here `==` operator puts a gap between result of pattern matching and evaluating if statement, hence the error. I don't know why `!` operator works fine, maybe they optimized that part but forgot to optimize this? ;)

I think this relates to Semantic Analysis phase of compiler, its job is to validate meaning of your code and determine how its executed, if there is something wrong, if there is possibility of undefined behavior or there is something totally meaningless, it fails and you get compile time error. read more about [Phases of Compiler Design](http://durofy.com/phases-of-compiler-design/)